# Escape !- -! inside strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, fitnesse

I have a javascript conversion tool for moving XML into Fitnesse tables running on a Fitnesse Static Page, in which I use `!-` and `-!` around CamelCase and xmlns to avoid Fitnesse from processing them. Ironically, the use of these is causing Fitnesse to interpret them when I run the conversion tool (I take a big string var and do a `$("#div").html(output);` which is causing some funkiness with Fitnesse.

I have the javascript running inside !- and -!, and when building these fitnesse tables, I set it up like this:

`|key|!-CamelCaseValue-!|`

The javascript looks like this:

`output += "!-" + currentValue + "-!";`

Fitnesse looks like it is ending the script here. How can I escape these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
var startToken = "!" + "-";
var endToken  = "-" + "!";

output += startToken + currentValue + endToken;
```

**Option 2**

```
output += "!\-" + currentValue + "-\!";
```

Comment: After messing with it some more, I got it working with option 1. Thanks